# Power Query: return self (this) query name

Tags: excel, this, powerquery, self

I was looking for a way for a query to reference its own name within the query itself. As far as I'm aware, there is no native function for this, so you have to get a bit tricky. Thought I'd share this solution I found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/96f24a90-41ef-4dba-98b8-fd1dceed3799/how-to-retrieve-self-this-query-name?forum=powerquery) by Bagration.555 after much digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that the last step is a single value for all queries that use this structure (0 in this case defined by `res` step). **The result is that the `self_name` step returns the name of the query.**

- `__Id__` can be any field name
- `555` can be any **static** value
- res can be any **static** value

```
let
    queries = Record.ToTable( #sections[Section1] ),
    select_marked = Table.SelectRows( queries, each Text.StartsWith( [Name], "YOUR_PREFIX")),
    choose_self = Table.AddColumn( select_marked, "__Id__", each try if Record.HasFields( Value.Metadata([Value]), "__Id__") then null else [Name] otherwise [Name] ),
    self_name = List.RemoveNulls(choose_self[__Id__]){0},
    res = 0 meta [__Id__ = 555]
in
    res
```

Comment: I too want to get the name of the query so I can parse it. IN my case, ive imported an Excel sheet has tabs with the name in the format "Food Log 20200511". Where the numbers are the date the tab refers to.  Each tab has data that needs to be merged into one table. And I need to get the date off the name of the tab.

So in Power Query each tab is it's own query with the name of the tab. 

Hence, if I can extract the date off the query I can put the date into its own column.

I was glad to find the above, except I cannot get it to work. 

Nor can I make heads or tail of it.

Comment: (Continued) For instance, in the choose_self step, it just returns a list of the queries previously selected in select_marked. I don't understand the use of Value.Metadata([Value] . Surely this is just trying to retrieve the metadata for [Value] and check if __Id__ exists. In my case [Value] is a Table object, since its the data in each sheet.     So there won't be any metadata information?      I don't understand the point of res. The only value it returns is 0. Why set a metadata value on it of __Id__ = 555?   I'm no expert at Power Query, so hopefully there may be an answer.

Comment: Hi @NormanCates, have you got solution to your problem. i have the same problem today. I have a query for each sheet from excel so i have to navigate and choose the sheet name, i want to just rename the query name and that should be reference to the sheet name